# How to set file name in response

Tags: python, response, pyramid

I know about content-disposition but I read what it uses for email messages. And I want to know how I can set file name with content-type.
ps I use Pyramid framework

edit:
Web site has button 'download' how to perform Response object for file name too, like

```
return Response(body=f.read(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

and what I need to do for showing correct file name in browser.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Is this for HTTP? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the filename parameter of the Content-Disposition header like so:

```
response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="my_filename.txt"'
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the `filename` equal to a variable?

Comment: For giving filename variable you can use as : response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % filename

Answer (score 0):

Use f string in python like below:

```
response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'
return response
```