# How can I rename a file in a Python Pyramid Response object?

Tags: python, response, pyramid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set file name in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991292/how-to-set-file-name-in-response)

I store files in MongoDB.  To serve a file from Pyramid, I do this:

```
# view file
def file(request):
    id = ObjectId(request.matchdict['_id'])
    collection = request.matchdict['collection']
    fs = GridFS(db, collection)
    f = fs.get(id)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(f.name)
    ext = ext.strip('.')
    if ext in ['pdf','jpg']:
        response = Response(content_type='application/%s' % ext)
    else:
        response = Response(content_type='application/file')
    response.app_iter = FileIter(f)
    return response
```

Using this method, the filename defaults to the `ObjectId` string of the file, which isn't pretty and lacks the correct file extension.  I've looked in the docs to see how/where I can rename the file inside the `Response` object, but I can't see it.  Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 100% foolproof way to set the filename. It's up to browsers to come up with a filename.

That said, you can use the `Content-Disposition` header to specify that you want the browser to *download* the file rather than *display* it, and you can also *suggest* a filename for the file to use for that file.  It looks like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

However, there is **no reliable cross-browser way to specify a filename with non-ascii characters**.  See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) for more details.  You also have to be careful to use a `quoted-string` encoding for the filename; you should construct a filename with all non-ascii characters removed and with `"` quoted with `\"`.

Now for the Pyramid-specific stuff.  Simply add a `Content-Disposition` header to your response. (Note that `application/file` is [not a valid mime type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html). Use `application/octet-stream` as a "generic" bag-of-bytes type.)

```
# "application/file" is not a valid mime type!
content_subtype = ext if ext in ['jpg','pdf'] else 'octet-stream'

# This replaces non-ascii characters with '?'
# (This assumes f.name is a unicode string)
content_disposition_filename = f.name.encode('ascii', 'replace')

response = Response(content_type="application/%s" % content_subtype,
                    content_disposition='attachment; filename="%s"' 
                      % content_disposition_filename.replace('"','\\"')
           )
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have to set the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
```

Comment: Virtual six-pack to you, my friend.