# Pyramid FileResponse changes name

Tags: python, pyramid

I am using `pyramid.response.FileResponse` to [serve file](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/static_assets/files.html)s. At browser file name changes automatically to some random name. For e.g, file I want to serve is `abc.zip` but, at client it prompts to store as `3PE01Sf_.zip.zip`. How to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set file name in response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991292/how-to-set-file-name-in-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991292/how-to-set-file-name-in-response) on similar line. it says use,

`response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="my_filename.txt"'`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the viewed file using a browser will depend on the route. If you look at the example in the doc the route points to '/test.jpg' but you are actually serving 'groundhog1.jpg'.

Alternatively depending on your source code, there maybe some library which generates the name of your dynamically created file, for example zip of PDF.