# Pyramid fileresponse with header

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm returning an image to my webpage with a pyramid [`fileResponse`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileResponse) like this:

```
response = FileResponse(newPath)
response.content_disposition = f'attachment; filename="{newImage}"'
return response
```

I get the file back fine, but i can't figure out how to add more parameters to this. I want to return the file and the name of the file. I've looked at questions like [How to set file name in response,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991292/how-to-set-file-name-in-response) but i can't seem to make this work.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078216/14526868) seems to suggest that i wouldn't even want to use `Content-Disposition`, because i am displaying it, but i can't find any other ways to add a parameter.

> That said, you can use the Content-Disposition header to specify that
> you want the browser to download the file rather than display it, and
> you can also suggest a filename for the file to use for that file. It
> looks like this:

How can i add another parameter to my `fileResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in your example is valid, you should see the `Content-Disposition` header set on the response that way. As far as displaying it instead of downloading as an attachment I believe that the final path segment plus in the URL itself dictates how the file will be named, plus possibly content type, when saving it by default. The disposition header just overrides that in certain situations.

Comment: Turns out that the library that i was using for getting the image, dropped the headers, so you are right. I realized when looking at the "Network" tab on Firefox and saw the header there.